Monte Carlo simulations and Jensen’s inequality in cost-effectiveness analysis: point estimates vs. expected values of simulations
In cost-effectiveness analysis, we use a cost-effectiveness ratio: effect/cost. Because it is a ratio, calculating and representing uncertainty around it is not straightforward. We can use Monte Carlo simulations to get an uncertainty distribution. We simulate the effect ~ N(M, SD) and the cost ~ N(M, SD) and then get a ratio of the two. This means that we now have two average values of the cost-effectiveness ratio possible:

The point estimate: E(effect)/E(cost)

The expected value of the simulation: E(effect ~ N(M, SD) / cost ~ N(M, SD)) = E(effect/cost) where we take the average of the Monte Carlo simulated distribution.


The problem is, E(effect)/E(cost) ≠ E(effect/cost), likely because of Jensen’s inequality. Which ones should I use?
I’d be especially grateful for somewhat authoritative references on this topic that I can point to.
This problem occurs for wider topics than cost-effectiveness, but it seems to be a particularly important issue here because it directly feeds into decision making. On the one hand, the distribution from the Monte Carlo simulation seems to be more informative about the pattern of cost-effectiveness outcomes that could occur. On the other hand, the simulations lose reciprocity: Namely, E(effect/cost) ≠ E(cost/effect). This is a problem because, say you are comparing the cost-effectiveness of two treatments, it could be that A > B on E(effect/cost) but B > A on E(cost/effect). If you think that the expected value of the simulation is the way to go, can you tell me how to deal with the loss of reciprocity?
The point estimate E(effect)/E(cost) has the nice property that it is easy to follow. If I tell you that the effect is 1 point and the cost is 10 dollars, then you can see how the cost-effectiveness is 0.1 points per dollar.
Discussion points and places I’ve looked at:
(1) Online: There have been a few different debates about this on this forum (see this post primarily). I am uncertain what the conclusions are here, but this seems to lean in favour of E(effect/cost).
(2) Health Economics Literature: Works like Briggs (2000; handling uncertainty in cost-effectiveness models) highlight the importance of accounting for parametric uncertainty in cost-effectiveness analysis. The implication is that simply using point estimates might not be sufficient when important uncertainty exists. I’ve tried looking into Baio’s (2022) Bayesian Methods in Health Economics book. However, I couldn’t find a clear answer. They force the distributions into point estimates when doing the ICER, but use the distributions when doing the IB and CEAC. I am uncertain what the conclusions are here.
(3) Bayesian Perspective: From my dipping into Bayesian analysis, such as in McElreath’s Rethinking Statistics (2nd Ed), I see that calculations are made with distributions rather than point estimates. For example, to calculate contrasts between two conditions – in a regression model where a mean value is estimated for two groups – the textbook does mean(g1-g2) (i.e., the expected value of the simulation), not mean(g1) - mean(g2) (i.e., the point estimate). This seems to lean in favour of E(effect/cost).
(4) Ratio of Averages (RoA) vs. Average of Ratios (AoR): This seems to be related to debates about RoA vs AoR. Stinnett and Paltiel (1996; Estimating CE Ratios under Second-order Uncertainty: The Mean Ratio versus the Ratio of Means) seems to be the most explicit source about all this. It strongly suggests that E(effect)/E(cost), akin to a Ratio of Averages, is the right way.
Bonus round: Bayesians and the Ratio of Averages vs. Average of Ratios considerations.
Can Stinnett and Paltiel (1996) be right about the Ratio of Means and Bayesians be right about doing calculations on the distributions? Maybe. I have a few tentative thoughts here but would need insight from people who actually know this stuff.
Say that instead of one value for effect and one value for costs, you had many studies which each had an effect and a cost value. The Ratio of Averages approach would tell you to first average the effects and then average the costs and then do the cost-effectiveness ratio, not the other way around. So, mean(effect)/mean(cost).
The Bayesian approach could very well agree with this, and do the same thing. Except they would also use the uncertainty around the average of effects (and do combination with a prior via Bayes rule) and use the uncertainty around the average of costs (and do combination with a prior via Bayes rule) and then divide the two uncertainty distributions to obtain an uncertainty distribution of the cost-effectiveness ratio. But they would not calculate cost-effectiveness ratios first, and then calculate an uncertainty distribution.
Namely, they would do: effect~N(M, SD) / cost~N(M, SD) not cost-effectiveness ratios ~N(M, SD).
Does anyone have a clear cut solution to this debate? Or some recommended reading to go further?
Thank you for your time!

I think you have already provided a fairly authoratative reference (Stinnett and Paltiel, 1996). Here's another way to show why the ratio of means is "consistent with first principles":
Let $Q$ be the effectiveness (e.g., QALYs gained or lost) and $C$ the cost savings or increases with intervention versus comparator. The intervention is cost-effective if its net benefit
$$NB = Q - \frac{C}{k},$$
is positive ($NB>0$), where $k > 0$ is the cost-effectiveness threshold (the cost at which the health system would produce a unit of effectiveness if funds were devoted to something other than the new intervention or the intervention is cost saving). Therefore, we expect the intervention to be cost effective when $E[NB] > 0$. If $k$ is treated as a constant (results are typically reported over a range of potentially relevant values of $k$), we have
$$ E[NB] = E[Q] - \frac{E[C]}{k} $$
\begin{align*}
E[NB] >0 \Rightarrow \left\{
\begin{aligned}
\frac{E[C]}{E[Q]} &< k \quad \text{for} \quad E[Q], E[C] > 0\\
\frac{E[C]}{E[Q]} &> k \quad \text{for} \quad E[Q], E[C] < 0
\end{aligned}
\right.
\end{align*}
That is, to confirm that the expected net benefit is positive, we should compare the ratio of means to the threshold. More generally, becasue the decision rules of cost-effectiveness analysis are derived based on the maximisation of net benefit, it is better to work with net benefits instead of cost-effectiveness ratios if you want your results to be consistent with "first principles", especially when uncertainty is involved. Some recomended references on this topic (if you aren't familiar with them already?):

Stinnett, A. A., & Mullahy, J. (1998). Net health benefits: a new framework for the analysis of uncertainty in cost-effectiveness analysis. Medical Decision Making, 18(2_suppl), S68-S80. https://doi.org/10.1177/0272989X98018002S09
Paulden, M. (2020). Why it’s time to abandon the ICER. PharmacoEconomics, 38(8), 781-784. https://doi.org/10.1007/s40273-020-00915-5
Paulden, M. (2020). Calculating and interpreting ICERs and net benefit. PharmacoEconomics, 38(8), 785-807. https://doi.org/10.1007/s40273-020-00914-6

It is perhaps also relevant to mention that the reason for prefering $f(E[x])$ over $E[f(x)]$ in this context is distinct from the reasoning we might apply in other contexts. For example, both effectiveness and costs are typically modeled as a non-linear function of some inputs ($\theta$). If $Q = f(\theta)$, then $E[Q] = E[f(\theta)]$ not $f(E[\theta])$. See for example:

Wilson, E. C. (2021). Methodological note: reporting deterministic versus probabilistic results of Markov, partitioned survival and other non-linear models. Applied Health Economics and Health Policy, 19, 789-795. https://doi.org/10.1007/s40258-021-00664-2

